# Return row in SQL that returning null value? to show them not as blank value

Tags: sql-server, null, notin

```
select *
from dataentry with (nolock)
where clientnumber in (
'00602',
'00897',
'00940'
)
```

So background is clientnumber is value that client sent to me and will be inserted into the database. But so the 3 numbers above aren't inserted in the database by me YET, so it will turn blank when I search them in database. Is there way for SQL to show those numbers as null value?

Maybe one to do this is using not IN with client numbers that I have already inserted? But let's say there are 2000 numbers I inserted, it would be very inefficient. What would be the best way to do this?

Comment: Side note: ["Bad habits : Putting NOLOCK everywhere"](https://www.sentryone.com/blog/aaronbertrand/bad-habits-nolock-everywhere)

Comment: hey sorry to bother you again, is there way to get it to show if I don't know the 3 values above? Let's say given a list, I want to show the null ones.

Comment: If that comment should address my answer: If you have a list, you know them. If you don't know them, you cannot show them of course. I'm not really getting what you're trying to say I'm afraid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can left join to a derived table containing the "numbers" (well, strings with a possible numeric representation actually).

```
SELECT d.clientnumber
       FROM (VALUES ('00602'),
                    ('00897'),
                    ('00940')) AS n
                                  (n)
            LEFT JOIN dataentry AS de
                      ON de.clientnumber = n.n;
```

That'll give you as many `NULL`s as "numbers" in the list that aren't present in the table and any "number" that is in the table the amount of times it is in it.

Or, what may be a bit more of a practical use, use `NOT EXISTS` to get the "numbers" not in the table (yet).

```
SELECT n.n AS clientnumber
       FROM (VALUES ('00602'),
                    ('00897'),
                    ('00940')) AS n
                                  (n)
       WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT *
                                FROM dataentry AS de
                                WHERE de.clientnumber = n.n);
```

Or even an indicator whether they are present or not.

```
SELECT n.n AS clientnumber,
       CASE
         WHEN EXISTS (SELECT *
                             FROM dataentry AS de
                             WHERE de.clientnumber = n.n) THEN
           'true'
         ELSE
           'false'
       END existence
       FROM (VALUES ('00602'),
                    ('00897'),
                    ('00940')) AS n
                                  (n);
```